# Force replication of Netlogon

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, replication, dfs, netlogon

I have added a batchfile to the the NETLOGON directory for some start-up scripts. The script is tiny in size.

I have waited hours  for the files to be replicated to the other Domain Controllers but the files have yet to be replicated.

I have also run `Repadmin /syncall`. I have stopped and re-started the `DFS service` on the Domain Controller where I added the files. I have used `replmon` as well to force replication.

What else can I try to speed up the process?

I have Windows Server 2003 on a domain.

Comment: Can you please try `repadmin /syncall /APed` and share the results with us? No replication errors?

Comment: Are the domain controllers in the same AD site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to be patient. It did eventually replicate. Thank for the assistance anyway.